# Error TS2339: Property 'Connection' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: typescript, ionic2

very simple issue

I am trying ang 2 and ionic 2.

Used following code -

main file -

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.d.ts" />


import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Network} from 'ionic-native'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/items-map/items-map.html'
})
export class ItemsMap {

  constructor(private platform : Platform) {
    console.log(navigator.Connection);
  }

}
```

NOw whenever I build the project using gulp build, i get -

> Error TS2339: Property 'Connection' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

Any help on same? I know there are some more similar issues logged, but none of the are having any definitive answers

Comment: You may use console.log(navigator.connection.type); May be it works!! I am also new to Ionic2 and ag2:)

Comment: It still gives same error

Comment: Will you check network on button click??

Comment: Right now was trying directly in constructor but it was not getting it..tried on actual device as well.. 

Comment: Ok...i just give you a link to prefer..i will not checked but you may prefer and may be you get what you need. Link: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/determine-network-availability-in-an-ionic-2-mobile-app/

Comment: You check that URL? Is it worked??

Comment: Still need to check it..not yet.

Comment: Yes I checked the url. Kind of same code base I have used

Comment: Ok...sorry, i have not any more idea about this.:)@Kaushik

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom type definitions for [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) based on the [W3C Spec Draft](https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/).

The Draft Community Group Report 11 May 2020 was used for the snippet below, with [`saveData`](https://wicg.github.io/savedata/#savedata-attribute) attribute from the Draft Community Group Report 12 January 2022.

```js
// network-information-api.d.ts
declare interface Navigator extends NavigatorNetworkInformation {}
declare interface WorkerNavigator extends NavigatorNetworkInformation {}
declare interface NavigatorNetworkInformation {
  readonly connection?: NetworkInformation
}
type Megabit = number
type Millisecond = number
type EffectiveConnectionType = '2g' | '3g' | '4g' | 'slow-2g'
type ConnectionType =
  | 'bluetooth'
  | 'cellular'
  | 'ethernet'
  | 'mixed'
  | 'none'
  | 'other'
  | 'unknown'
  | 'wifi'
  | 'wimax'
interface NetworkInformation extends EventTarget {
  readonly type?: ConnectionType
  readonly effectiveType?: EffectiveConnectionType
  readonly downlinkMax?: Megabit
  readonly downlink?: Megabit
  readonly rtt?: Millisecond
  readonly saveData?: boolean
  onchange?: EventListener
}
```

Native support for Network Information API in [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) was added in [#44842](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44842) with limited attributes.

Answer (score 2):

This is TypeScript Definition problem. It need TypeScript definition for the plugin. Use npm to install it.

> npm install @types/cordova-plugin-network-information --save

If it doesn't work, try `Network.type` instead of `navigator.connection`.

Comment: Using instance of Network within the component helps get the information.

Answer (score 1):

If you change it to "`navigator['connection']`" that might solve the problem, or as someone suggested "`navigator.type`". 
But I see a lil issue in your code, you haven't declare the "`navigator`"! I suggest you do that above the the `@Component decorator`, add it as follows:

```
declare var navigator; 
@Component decorator({
           .....
})
```

and then change to "navigator.type" or to "navigator['connection'], whatever suits you!

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is incorrect as `navigator` is by default on the `window` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already importing the [Network](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/) class so you can get the connection type by calling `Network.connection`. The underlying code for this property will return `navigator.connection.type`.

Because this way you are accessing it through Ionic's TypeScript declaration class (network.d.ts) the error will no longer occur.

Note, when using the Network class be sure to add the Cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-network-information` to your config.xml file.

**Example**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Network} from 'ionic-native'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/items-map/items-map.html'
})
export class ItemsMap {

  constructor(private platform : Platform) {
    console.log(Network.connection);
  }
}
```