# Typescript NetworkInformation type does not contain all properties

Tags: typescript, navigator

I want to access `effectiveType` and `downlink` properties of the [NetworkInformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation) object.

I know that these properties may not exist depending on the browser, I'm checking that as follows:

```js
const info: string[] = ['Downloading...'];
if ('connection' in window.navigator) {
  info.push(`Connection Type: ${navigator.connection.effectiveType}`);
  if ('downlink' in window.navigator.connection) {
    info.push(`Speed: ${navigator.connection.downlink} MB/s`);
  }
}
```

But the type contains only the `type` property. Though when I'm printing that object in the console it has all the properties I'm expecting:

[image]

What should I do to get past the typescript errors?

> Property 'downlink' does not exist on type 'NetworkInformation'.ts(2339)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error TS2339: Property 'Connection' does not exist on type 'Navigator'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383676/error-ts2339-property-connection-does-not-exist-on-type-navigator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Problem

The type for `NetworkInformation` exists in `lib.dom.d.ts` and, at the time of writing, looks like this:

```
interface NetworkInformation extends EventTarget {
    readonly type: ConnectionType;
}
```

– [lib.dom.d.ts L10430-L10432 @ 65ae16c](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/65ae16cdea7ec887a6a16f9e709a07c2abe88387/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L10430-L10432)

Unfortunately `downlink` and `effectiveType` (and more) do not exist on there yet.

The DOM lib is actually generated by a tool: [TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator). In the readme, it has the following:

> ### Why is my fancy API still not available here?
>
> A feature needs to be supported by two or more major browser engines to be included here, to make sure there is a good consensus among vendors: **Gecko** (Firefox), **Blink** (Chrome/Edge), and **WebKit** (Safari).

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator#why-is-my-fancy-api-still-not-available-here)

> ### When the type is missing
>
> It's possible that the automated algorithm decided that it's not well supported by browsers and thus removed it. Say we want to add a new interface named `Foo`. Check if there is a document about that interface in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/). If there is, see the browser compatibility section and check whether it's supported by two or more browser engines. (Note that Chromium-based browsers use the same browser engine and thus support from them counts as a single support.)

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-DOM-lib-generator#when-the-type-is-missing)

Checking the browser compatibility table for [`NetworkInformation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation), it looks like this at the time of writing:

|  | Chrome | Edge | Firefox | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `NetworkInformation` (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | 79 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | 48 ✅ | No ❌ |
| `downlink` (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | 79 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | 48 ✅ | No ❌ |
| `downlinkMax` (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ |
| `effectiveType` (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | 79 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | 48 ✅ | No ❌ |
| `onchange` (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | 79 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | 48 ✅ | No ❌ |
| `ontypechange` (Experimental ) (Deprecated ) (Non-standard ⚠️) | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ | Unknown ❓ | No ❌ |
| `rtt` (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | 79 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | 48 ✅ | No ❌ |
| `saveData` (Experimental ) | 65 ✅ | 79 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | Yes | No ❌ |
| `type` (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ | No ❌ |
| Available in workers (Experimental ) | 61 ✅ | 79 ✅ | No ❌ | No ❌ | 48 ✅ | No ❌ |

– [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation#browser_compatibility)

Looking at the above table it looks like only Blink/Chromium based browsers (Chrome, Edge and Opera) support various parts of the `NetworkInformation` interface. Gecko and WebKit do not. As a result it doesn't meet the test that two or more major browser engines need to be supported for an API to be added to the types.

As for why `NetworkInformation` even exists in the types in the first place, I don't know. But you can see how it got in via [`lib.dom.d.ts`'s blame](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blame/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L10430-L10432) in GitHub.

## Solution

You can author your own types or use the types that someone else has authored [here](https://github.com/lacolaco/network-information-types).

Comment: Interestingly, that `network-information-types` package was deprecated, stating the types had been built into TS's lib.dom.d.ts, but as of version 5, I can't find `NetworkInformation`, `ConnectionType`, or any other related types in it. Maybe they moved or renamed them...? Or maybe they removed them if this was taken off the standards track?

Comment: @V.Rubinetti: Looks like it was removed in TS 4.8. See commit [9a09c37](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/9a09c37878a45b06994485fdb510eb4d24587dcb#diff-796971dc74a3f3cd77ca0a3a776d6fe27ab224cd501d9652dbeffcf45ba0f058L10430). Unfortunately, I don't know why. Regardless, the solution in the answer still stands – author your own types or install the linked package (you can install deprecated packages but obviously balance the risks). Consider letting the package author know of this situation as well.